# how to instantiate a new local variable in a lua_state?

Tags: variables, lua, instance, local

I need to instantiate new variables in *lua_state*, but these variables must be **local**.
Until then, I know only set global variables with *lua_setglobal*. I know there
*lua_setlocal*, but I do not know how to handle a lua_Debug.

The question is, how to instantiate a new **local** variable in a *lua_state*?

Comment: Local to what? Local variables are local to a block of Lua code.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it that you're actually trying to accomplish by creating this local variable?

Answer (score 1):

A local variable is really just a place on the Lua stack (unless the local is from an out-of-function scope) that compiled code can read. The set of local available to a piece of Lua code is *fixed at compile-time*. So the only way to affect it is to edit the actual *text* of your Lua script to add a local. And two Lua scripts can't share locals.

In short, what you want isn't possible and doesn't make sense.